# Detect 'no internet' connectivity error in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

How can I detect no internet connection error with Retrofit 2?

What I used to do in Retrofit 1 is to implement Client interface and perform connectivity check at execute(Request request).

What I attempted in Retrofit 2 is:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

    @Inject
    public RequestInterceptor(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
        this.connectivityManager = connectivityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        if (isConnected()) {
            throw new OfflineException("no internet");
        }

        Request.Builder r = chain.request().newBuilder();
        return chain.proceed(r.build());
    }

    protected boolean isConnected() {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

I am able to catch it with synchronous Retrofit execution by adding a try-catch block, but not with asynchronous where error is returned as parameter of OnFailure(Call call, Throwable t). App just crashes with OfflineException I throw in the interceptor.

Comment: Btw, you are performing unnecessary object allocations when building a new request. Just call `chain.proceed(chain.request())`.

Comment: @awonderer - This method just checks the network connection or does it also check internet connectivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution.**

My `OfflineException` class has to inherit `IOException`